# A a little bit difference in the operation

Tags: c#, nullable

```
class Program {

        static bool? a = null;
        static bool b = false;

        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            //1
            if( a!=null ) {
                b = (bool) a;
            }
            //2
            if( a!=null && (b=(bool) a) ) { }
        }
    }
```

Is there any difference between the case #1 and the case #2?

Comment: You could check the IL yourself with `ildasm`, you know.

Comment: In case #2, is it on purpose to have no code inside `{ }`? I think case #2 is not logical as you are using the expression just to assign a value to b. Case #2, or better yet, Oded's answer, makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of the value `b` will get, they are functionally the same.

Though, since you are using nullables, you should be using their features:

```
if(a.HasValue)
   b = a.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could write:

```
b = (a.HasValue) ? a.Value : b;
```

Although I have to say that @Oded's answer is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

yes, case one fires if a isnt null, case 2 only fires if a isnt null AND if b = bool a